# woocommerce add to cart button ajax clear cash after adding

Tags: php, ajax, caching, woocommerce

Hi all I have big problem with Woocommerce add to cart button.
When I select th quantity of item 1 and press add to cart button after that if i change quantity to 2 or 3 or 4 it add just one item. if i first add 2 item after that it add only 2 items. somehow it save the first selected quantity and save it on cache. So I need your help.

http://galerieroyale.am/place-an-order/

this is a working website you can see it when add to cart a item and see the ajax request after first select the quantity still same.
If you have some idea you can i remove quantiy from cache after addin to cart it well be helpfull

ajax request after first adding

```
action=woocommerce_add_to_cart&quantity=1&product_id=185
```

you can see that the quantity doesn't change

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add to cart via ajax on the single product page isn't default WooCommerce behavior, so it is something in another extension or likely in your custom theme. You are going to need to show some code, because the `data-quantity="3"` clearly changes on the second attempt, so the problem is possibly in the add to cart callback. Also, auto-playing music?

Comment: I can't show the code sorry. but when you add item to cart after that somehow it save the cuantity number on cache and doesn't change it after selecting other cuantity

Comment: I can't fix code I can't look at. Good luck with your problem.